# General term for T[], T*, and T&

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, terminology

An array of *T*, a pointer to *T*, and a reference to *T* (represented as `T[]`, `T*`, and `T&` respectively by `Type.ToString`) all share the similarity that they are constructed from an "element" type (which can be returned by `Type.GetElementType`). What is the correct term to address all these types? I am inclined to say "derived" or "constructed" types, but the former can be confused with inheritance and the latter with generics. Multidimensional arrays could also fall under the term.

Comment: FWIW, in C++ they're called _compound types_. I have no idea what they call them in C# but you could check that it's not that.

Comment: @PreferenceBean If I remember correctly, classes and structs are called *compound* types by the specification.

Comment: True, more types exist in the set of C++ compound types than just arrays-of, pointers-to and references-to. I'm not aware of a name for just those. Perhaps the same is true in C#?

Comment: @PreferenceBean There are apparently compound or composite types, composite types encompassing user-defined classes, structs, and also arrays, while compound types just classes and structs. It's a mess anyway. Pointers etc. aren't really composite, because they can't be broken down into smaller typed units, although they are based on a type.

Comment: @DocBrown T& exists in .NET and CIL as a kind of pointer, and this question is also tagged .NET (maybe should I change it to `ref T`?). I need the generic term because all these types share that *GetElementType* method, which categorizes them in a way.

Comment: @IllidanS4 If you're referring to `unsafe` code, Microsoft simply calls those "pointers."  See [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Pointers are `T*`, not `T&`. And `T[]` is not a pointer (usually).

Comment: Microsoft calls `T&` "AddressOf," just like C++ does.  `T[]` is an "Array of type T."  There isn't a universal term that embodies all of these concepts, other than they all use *pointers* in some manner.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Where? In ECMA it is called a managed pointer, and ByRef in the CLI.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx), where Microsoft calls it the "AddressOf" operator (though they put the ampersand in front, rather than behind, the variable).  The AddressOf operator is *only used in an `unsafe` context* (i.e. *unmanaged code*).  A "managed pointer" is something else; that would simply be a "reference" in managed code, not a pointer at all (the underlying "pointer" mechanism is an implementation detail).  The memory address of a reference in managed code is not available to the programmer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The location of the ampersand is quite an important fact. An ampersand before a variable is indeed the "adress of" *operator*, which is present in both C# and C++. However, an ampersand after a type marks a byref type in .NET methods and CIL (not in C#, where it is marked with `ref` before it). Hope I've made it clear.

Comment: You're making this much harder than it is.  The answer to your basic question is "No, there is no term that encompasses all of these things."

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://csharppad.com/gist/7b7474dc3cfca4f7e0c1 for the .NET Type.ToString and [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) page 122 lists "Type `‘&’`".

Comment: Not sure what you need the term for, but if it's so obscure that nobody can recognize it, it's not going to be of much use in documentation unless you explain the term first.  Much like a joke; if you have to explain the joke, it's not a very good joke.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Apparently I am making this much more confusing for people who aren't used to `T&` notation. Unfortunately, there is no *CIL* tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36137/discussion-between-illidans4-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, functions that take a type and return another type are called type constructors.

That term should be well known amongst functional languages, but less so in mainstream languages - often because the array notation is the only one used.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, T[] can be referred to as arrays or "covariant arrays", which both C# and Java have.  Some language critiques think that the covariant arrays were a mistake, and would have been different had generics been in the language from the start.

C# does not have "reference to T" (e.g. `T&` as we find in C++).   While you can take the address of something, that becomes a pointer type (like in C).  C# has out and ref parameters, but C# considers the type of `out int abc` as simply `int` (not `int&`, which doesn't exist in C#) that must be assigned before leaving the method normally.

C# does have pointers, which can only be used in an unsafe context.  While arrays are a "managed" type (i.e. garbage collected and type-safe), pointers are not.  You can take the address of an array element into a pointer, but to use it properly, you would have to pin the array so that the runtime/gc doesn't move or remove it, as in some sense this is mixing managed and unmanaged types.

Thus, I don't think there is an umbrella term in C# for these three types, as one isn't supported, and the other two are managed vs. unmanaged, which can be related, but are rather different beasts.

Comment: [Reference Types in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey He probably meant references (also known as managed pointers and byrefs), not reference types. 
C# supports references in a very limited way, only via `ref` parameters and arguments. However, .NET fully supports manipulation with references like C++.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks for the "reference" (ar ar) ;)   What the language is calling reference types, in the parlance of the OP, would be just `T` (where `T` extends `Object` (and not value type)).